# Passing xpath from CSV to replace value in XML with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv, xpath, apostrophe

Looking to read a list of xml elements (as xpaths) & their new values from a csv file -> and then, look into an existing xml file to replace whatever xml elements are to be updated, with the new values on the given xpaths.

I got the values for the xpaths I need to change in the big xml by online parsing it.  There can/will be any number of values to replace at one time, so I can't hard-code these into the powershell - it will need to read each set of changes required each time - from a file (the csv), I am suggesting.

One xpath target to replace a value is is :

```
    /configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value[0]/text()
```

So I have the csv line as:

```
    "/configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value[0]/text()","new value"
```

I then call a fn to replace this xpath with the new value, in the xml.

I am struggling **on just that one line**, where the "-" in app-args xpath string above, is being parsed and somehow cutting the xpath string short there, and therefore tripping out the replace.  I can't change the node names in the xml - not an option.

I can browse the xml structure in powershell when I load it:

```
    $xml = [xml](Get-Content "C:\temp\big.xml")
```

So autocomplete browsing on prompt, I can then see that:

```
    PS c:\temp> $xml.configuration.services.objects.object.'app-args'.list.value[0]
```

will show me the correct "replace this value 1" in the xml.

But I can't get the xpath phrasing correct in the csv to replace this node.  How can I read that node with the "-" in the name, from a file? I've tried /"app-args"/ and a host of other escape chars but out of ideas for now.  Use something other than csv?

No experience with xpath before and it's really killing me!

Ref: (simplified) xml with problem area is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <spring xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.net ../../../../lib/spring.net/spring-objects-1.1.xsd">
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
      <context name="services">
        <resource uri="config://spring/services/objects" />
      </context>
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" default-autowire="constructor">
      <object name="SomeServicefactory" type="ServiceFactory" />
    </objects>
    <services>
      <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" default-lazy-init="true">
        <object name="SystemConfiguration" type="SystemConfiguration">
          <app-args name="ConfigCodes">
            <list element-type="string">
              <value>old value</value>
              <!-- Automate me -->
              <!-- use case, assume default value as per above, allow the powershell module to override this -->
              <value>old value</value>
              <!-- Automate me -->
              <!-- use case, assume default value as per above, allow the powershell module to override this -->
            </list>
          </app-args>
        </object>
      </objects>
    </services>
  </spring>
</configuration>
```

And the most simple csv I am using is (xpath,new value for it):

```
    "/configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value[0]/text()","new value 1"
    "/configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value[1]/text()","new value 2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are providing an example which has namespace, that will have a little bit of a different way to define your paths.

Your XML tags namespace at objects, so everything under objects is considered to be part of a specific namespace. This namespace is necessary when looking up, editing or deleting nodes.

```
$xml.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/services/x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[1]", $Namespace)
$Namespace = New-Object -TypeName "Xml.XmlNamespaceManager" -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable
$Namespace.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.springframework.net")
```

Since `/configuration/services` are outside of that namespace, you dont have to tag them with that `namespaceManager`. But everything under, and including, `objects` will have to be tagged.

If you are interested in changing the values, you will need to update the `InnerText` of the elements.

```
$xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/services/x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[1]", $Namespace).InnerText = "New Value for First"

# or you can use // to search for the first element
$xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[1]", $Namespace).InnerText = "New Value for First"
```

Also note, value is indexed starting with 1. There is no `value[0]`. From all of this, your csv will need to be updated to include the namespace tags.

```
"//x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[1]","new value 1"
"//x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[2]","new value 2"
```

**Complete Code**

```
$Namespace = New-Object -TypeName "Xml.XmlNamespaceManager" -ArgumentList $xml.NameTable
$Namespace.AddNamespace("x", "http://www.springframework.net")

$csv = Get-Content C:\temp\csv.txt
[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\temp\xml.txt

foreach($line in $csv) {
    $items = $line.Replace("""", "").Split(",") # Remove extra quotes
    $xml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode($items[0], $Namespace).InnerText = $Items[1]
}
$xml.Save("C:\temp\new.txt")
```

**new.txt** content:

```
<configuration>
  <services>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" default-lazy-init="true">
      <object name="SystemConfiguration" type="SystemConfiguration">
        <app-args name="Codes">
          <list element-type="string">
            <value>new value 1</value>
            <value>new value 2</value>
          </list>
        </app-args>
      </object>
    </objects>
  </services>
</configuration>
```

**--------------------------------------------------------**

**Suggested Solution with updated question**

Based on your new xml, i would recommend going with the `Select-XML` route.

**CSV**

```
"//ns:objects/ns:object/ns:app-args/ns:list/ns:value[1]","new value 1"
"//ns:objects/ns:object/ns:app-args/ns:list/ns:value[2]","new value 2"
```

**CODE**

```
$csv = Get-Content C:\temp\csv.txt
[xml]$xml = Get-Content C:\temp\xml.txt

$ns = @{ns='http://www.springframework.net'}
foreach($line in $csv) 
{
    $items = $line.Replace("""", "").Split(",") # Remove extra quotes
    $nodeRef = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath $items[0] -Namespace $ns
    $nodeRef.Node.InnerText = $items[1]
}

$xml.Save("C:\temp\new.txt")
```

New file has the values updated.

Please mark the post answered if it answers the issue in your post.

Comment: Hi Jawad, Thanks for your input so far.  Really appreciate the time you have spent to look at this.  I didn't know how the namespaces in the the xml would impact the xpath nodes.  Good stuff.  The ps1 you need to declare the $xml at the top before you reference it in the $namespace var. :)

The actual xml has **two** namespace settings in it, I will edit the Qn as I can't post it in a comment.  Take a look.

Comment: I used that code (after declaring $xml before declaring $Namespace :) ) and on line 1 in csv:
```"/configuration/spring/services/x:objects/x:object/x:constructor-arg/x:list/x:value[1]","new value 1"
```
..It throws "The property 'InnerText' cannot be found on this object.."

Comment: Nice catch. I updated the post to move $xml declaration up. You can declare different namespaces.. use a different letter or word for that matter when adding another.. Namespace.AddNamespace(anything = ''). then use this 'anything' in your csv lines.

Comment: So given the xml namepsaces above, how do I reference the xpath using them?  The line above still errors using
        configuration/services/x:objects/x:object/x:app-args/x:list/x:value[1]

Comment: many thanks.  That works.  The error was thrown on a blank line at the end of the csv which I'll validate going forward.  :very grateful emoji:

Answer (score 2):

XPath is the path you use to find a node using `SelectNodes` (to get a number of nodes that match the path) or `SelectSingleNode` to get first match.  When you update the node that you retrieved, you update the parent $xml as well since Node is a reference to part of the parent document.

**Usage**

```
$xpath = "/configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value[0]/text()"
$node = $xml.SelectSingleNode($XPath)
$node.Value = "newValue"

$xml.Save("PathToSave")
```

if you have multiple nodes at some place, you can use `SelectNodes` to get a list of nodes then iterate over these to update the values.

```
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//configuration/services/objects/object/app-args/list/value")
foreach($node in $nodes) {
    // Do something with $node.attribute $node.something 
}
```

Without seeing the actual layout of your xml, not sure how to suggest another way.

Comment: I have already got code to replace the node value.  The problem is passing an xpath from a csv into this code, where the xpath contains "-".

Comment: Can you provide sample xml

Comment: Thank you Jawad, xml and csv added.